# Parameter count mismatch when posting to Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the C# Facebook SDK to create an app. I am calling the Graph API with several different `POST` and `GET` operations and they all work fine.

The only place where I'm having an issue is with the following code:

```
try
{
   var path = string.Format("/{0}/likes", fbPostId);
   result = await client.PostTaskAsync(path);

   return result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   /* Removed catch code, since it is irrelevant */

}
```

When I run this, after the `PostTaskAsync` line I get an exception with a message of `Parameter Count Mismatch`. I was thinking that maybe I was missing parameters in the request itself, so I looked this up in the Graph API reference, and it does not require any other parameters (that I can see anyway).
I also thought it might have something to do with the rewriting involved in `async-await`, so I changed the code from using `PostTaskAsync` to a synchronous `Post` and I also got the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason (and I can't find anything about this in the documentation) the call to `PostTaskAsync` should look like this:

```
result = await client.PostTaskAsync(path, new {});
```

I don't understand why the anonymous object is required, but has no compile-time checking, but anyway, this works.